event.preventDefault() doesn't work on form submission
This sounds like the stupidest problem I've ever encountered, but this simple thing doesn't work. The page refreshes every time I press 'Submit' button. Any ideas why?
Here is my code:


const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');

const submitForm = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Hi');
};

submitBtn.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
<form>
    <label>Input your facebook profile URL</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>




Shouldn't you bind the submit action on the form?

The button does not have a submit event. Only the form has. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent

This question is similar to: JavaScript code to stop form submission. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"The page refreshes every time I press 'Submit' button" - always debug your code.  Don't just run and it throw your hands in the air.   The preventDefault() isn't "working" because the code never gets there.  So your question should be: why is my event handler not working?

You need to change your event name "submit" to click! And, good practice. Define the type of the button like this
<button type="submit"></button>


@DanielMichelfelder there are other ways to "submit" a form than just clicking a button.  If those other ways are removed, then yes - click handler.  Otherwise, moving the submit handler to the form would be the correct solution.

Actually, the answer to the latter question is: <form> with no defined action attribute will assume document.URL, plus, <button> default behavior inside a form is to submit the form, so that's why "The page refreshes every time I press 'Submit' button.". As your form is actually being sent and there's no field/data in the form to fill the GET method (default <form> method attribute value), the page just reloads. The answer for the first question (the title) is in the first and second comments.

As others point out, the submit event is on the form, not the button. You can use the form property of the button:
submitBtn.form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);


Enough rep to mark as typo-type instead of answering.

@mplungjan I am not aware of the typo-type (voted to reopen) please explain

It is closed with the "This question is not reproducible or was caused by typos." which is a reasonable close. Sufficient information in the comments made almost 10 minutes before your answer. The question cannot be deleted when there is an answer and the answer cannot be deleted if there are upvotes and only one answer. No need to re-open. It is a huge dupe as well

@mplungjan, "This question was caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced.". It's unreasonable because there's no typo and the problem CAN be reproduced. It's a legit problem in the logic, with this valid answer correcting the logic.

It’s the closest to “the solution is to do this instead of that, and there are hundreds of dupes we cannot be bothered to look up because the issue is using the wrong event/mehod/attribute/element; and the solution has been given in the comments”

I voted to close this issue as a typo because I thought using the submit event instead of the click event on a button is a typo. After giving second thoughts I agree this is not a typo, at the same time I am quite sure that this is not a new question and you can easily find various duplicates.

From my perspective, the quality of SO went sharply down since high rep users wanted to transform it into encyclopedia, promoting old questions with outdated answers, discouraging new users from participating. Much was proposed to address this, little was implemented. I don't see any duplicate in the linked and related questions.
